# LuaJIT, corrupted Lua stack, and getting the global table

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm currently working to migrate a game ([Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org/)) from Lua 5.1 to LuaJIT 2.0.2.  I have gotten it to compile and link appropriately; but, when running the game and actually trying to run a lua script (for a robot), I seem to get a corrupted stack.

The problem occurs when attempting to set the environment for the script - I grab the global environment before making a copy:

```
lua_pushvalue(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);                      // -- globalEnv
```

However, when dumping the stack here, the stack has 1 item that is a `LUA_TSTRING` with a value of `NULL` (stack was empty beforehand).  This had no problems when linking against the normal Lua 5.1 library and the above call correctly pushed the global table onto the stack.

I read that this could mean the stack was corrupted elsewhere and that LuaJIT is less forgiving than the normal VM.  I turned on `-DLUA_USE_ASSERT` and `-DLUA_USE_APICHECK` compiler flags for LuaJIT, but nothing is being triggered.

Before setting up a script's environment, we do load several scripts into the global environment using `lua_pcall` as well as set up several other globals using the C API.  Could these cause an unknown stack corruption like this?

How can I find the stack corruption?  Or, am I missing something else important with LuaJIT?

Comment: it sounds like one of this times where a minimal use-case that reproduces the bug would be really helpful in pinning down the problem.

Comment: I've been attempting this for a while now.  Since I have not had success, I asked how to proceed here.  My minimal test cases work fine, but Bitfighter has a lot of complex code bound with Lua.  I need to find out where the problem is, but compiling with asserts isn't doing anything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more trial-and-error, I found that our build system was pulling in Lua headers from a different Lua distribution before those of LuaJIT's.  This was causing the corrupt stack.

After removing the hard-coded `#include` directives to the old distribution, and properly putting LuaJIT's headers on the compile path, I was able to successfully manipulate the global stack again.

Comment: +1 for figuring it out yourself AND posting the solution to your own answer!

Comment: I figure just the act of asking for help sometimes gives you inspiration enough to solve your own problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on assertions for Lua and see what happens. It is often the case that you get away with some stuff in Lua that LuaJIT is not so lenient about. Turning assertions on for Lua will help you isolate the problem (is it your code - most likely or LuaJIT itself)

Comment: Why -1? It is a known fact that turning assertions in Lua on reveals undetected stack corruptions...

Comment: I followed the instructions in the Makefile to turned on assertions by compiling with those LuaJIT compiler flags I mentioned.  Was there something else I needed to do?

Comment: @W.B. Probably someone who doesn't yet know that just because a suggestion didn't work doesn't mean it should be downvoted. If the answer is a useful step to attempt, and enables ruling out certain types of problems, then it be probably be upvoted if anything.